Exporting to FBX breaks texture, adding polygons
I have been trying for hours to figure out what the issue is. I was using tiny eye procedural add-on and baked the textures as show in the tutorial because I need to import to unity. But when exporting to fbx all the textures in the eyes break and poly tripled Does anyone have clue whats going on? Everything is just fine before export. I'm use blender 4.2






@GordonBrinkmann The current consensus is that third-party addons are not out of topic here. It's only troubleshooting/debugging or paywalled 3rd-party addons that can't be properly answered.

Agree for the subdiv modifier, it's visible from the bent wireframe in the 3rd screenshot. Eirher disable the modifier, or disable "apply modifiers" in the FBX export options.

Eyes made somewhat realistically (with layers of meshes with transmission, diffraction and whatnot) aren't as easy to export as a simple matter of baking textures and exporting. Firstly it's not the most optimal thing to replicate in a video game environment, for performance reasons and also the game engine might simply not have the tech to do it efficiently in the first place. You have to study how this particular eye system is made, which layers do what, what can be baked, what should be simplified for real time rendering, ....

@GordonBrinkmann So, just letting you know.

I actually don't have any modifiers unapplied other than armature. But from the above i figured it was something far beyond my level of understanding. I have since just made a new eye with uv sphere and drawn texture.
